# programmatically attaching file to file media

Tags: 8, media

I am trying to programmatically attach a file to a node, using the media module now included in core as of Drupal 8.5.0.

I wrote this drush script to stub out the creation of a new `file` media content piece.

```
<?php

use \Drupal\node\Entity\Node;
use \Drupal\file\Entity\File;
use \Drupal\media\entity\Media;

$file = file_save_data(uniqid(), 'public://test' . uniqid() . '.txt');

$drupalMedia = Media::create([
  'bundle' => 'file',
  'uid' => '0',
  'file' => [
    'target_id' => $file->id(),
  ],
]);

$drupalMedia->setName(uniqid())
  ->setPublished(TRUE)
  ->save();
```

When I navigate to the site's media at `admin/content/media`, I see my media listed:

[image]

But when I edit the piece of media, my text file is not attached to it:

[image]

There are no error messages in watchdog.

What am I missing? What do I need to do to attach the file to the media?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The key for file needed to be `field_media_file` instead of `file`.